# Why is `par(mfrow=c(3,2))` not working here with `densityplot()`?

Tags: r, lattice

`densityplot()` is from the lattice package. Running following commands, I get one plot per page/figure, instead of all 6 plots arranged in a page/figure. Why? Here `output` is the return of `BRugsFit()` with `coda=TRUE`, where there are 78 parameters and 2 chains, and I pick 6 parameters from them:

```
Sigma12 = mcmc.list(list(output[[1]][,2], output[[2]][,2]))
Sigma22 = mcmc.list(list(output[[1]][,3], output[[2]][,3]))
alpha1 = mcmc.list(list(output[[1]][,4], output[[2]][,4]))
beta1 = mcmc.list(list(output[[1]][,5], output[[2]][,5]))
gamma_alpha_1 = mcmc.list(list(output[[1]][,75], output[[2]][,75]))
gamma_beta_1 = mcmc.list(list(output[[1]][,77], output[[2]][,77]))

> par(mfrow=c(2,3)); 
> densityplot(Sigma12, main="Sigma12")
> densityplot(Sigma22, main="Sigma22")
> densityplot(alpha1, main="alpha1")
> densityplot(beta1, main="beta1")
> densityplot(gamma_alpha_1, main="gamma_alpha_1")
> densityplot(gamma_beta_1, main="gamma_beta_1")
> 
> class(Sigma12)
[1] "mcmc.list"
```

Things also don't work out with  `acfplot()` from `coda`:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3)); 
acfplot(Sigma12, main="Sigma12")
acfplot(Sigma22, main="Sigma22")
acfplot(alpha1, main="alpha1")
acfplot(beta1, main="beta1")
acfplot(gamma_alpha_1, main="gamma_alpha_1")
acfplot(gamma_beta_1, main="gamma_beta_1")
```

But it works with `traceplot()` from `coda`.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3)); 
traceplot(Sigma12, main="Sigma12")
traceplot(Sigma22, main="Sigma22")
traceplot(alpha1, main="alpha1")
traceplot(beta1, main="beta1")
traceplot(gamma_alpha_1, main="gamma_alpha_1")
traceplot(gamma_beta_1, main="gamma_beta_1")
```

Changing `mcmc.list()` to be `as.mcmc.list()` in the above code doesn't make difference either.

Comment: par is base graphics. Lattice is grid graphics. Two entirely different graphics systems. Look into the gridExtra package and grid.arrange.

Comment: Thanks! How can I make the plots into one figure/page?

Comment: Like I said: grid.arrange from the gridExtra package.

Comment: Thanks! I read its man page, but still couldn't figure out how to use grid.arrange to solve my problem.

Comment: If you google grid.arrange you will find many, many examples of its use.

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up, I was being terse in the comments because I was on my phone. Using the example from `?densityplot`, usage goes something like this:

```
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- densityplot( ~ height | voice.part, data = singer, layout = c(2, 4),  
             xlab = "Height (inches)", bw = 5)
grid.arrange(p1,p1,nrow = 1)
```